# Are the algebraic numbers recursive?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

I am interested in a theory I call Modular Arithmetic (MA). MA has the same axioms as first order [Peano arithmetic (PA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) except $\forall x Sx \neq 0$ is replaced with $\exists x Sx=0$. MA has finite models: the commutative rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

MA is an [ill-founded theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) and all infinite models of MA are [non-standard](http://lesswrong.com/lw/g0i/standard_and_nonstandard_numbers/). The [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field) is a countably infinite non-standard model of MA. [Tennenbaum's theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6375) says neither addition nor multiplication can be recursive in a non-standard model of arithmetic. Tennenbaum's theorem almost certainly applies to MA. Despite this, we can do arithmetic with algebraic numbers using the rules for [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Elementary_operations).

Given the algebraic numbers as a model of MA, are addition and multiplication recursive in this model? If so, what prevents me from encoding a non-recursive set as an algebraic number? If addition and multiplication are not recursive in this model then what type of operations aren't computable?

---

By algebraic numbers I mean the field of algebraic numbers which is algebraically closed. This includes the complex algebraic numbers.

The standard definition $x \leq y \iff \exists z(x+z=y)$ does not work in MA because of the way modular arithmetic works. Consider that $(2+1=3) mod 4$ and $(3+3=2) mod 4$ proving $2 \leq 3$ and $3 \leq 2$ in the model $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. This is why MA is an ill-founded theory. MA is also [$\omega$-inconsistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory). The statement $\forall x(Sx \neq 0)$ is true for all standard natural numbers in any infinite model of MA. $\omega$-inconsistent theories can't have a standard infinite model.

Tennenbaum's theorem is a proof by contradiction that applies to very weak theories of arithmetic. MA is a relatively strong theory. The question is whether a non-recursive set of standard natural numbers can be encoded as a non-standard number. In the algebraic numbers, any number that is not a standard natural number is a non-standard natural number. For example, $-1, \frac{1}{2}$, and $i$ are all "infinite" natural numbers in this model. Tennenbaum's proof uses [overspill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overspill).

Assume we have a non-recursive set of natural numbers. One way to encode this set is by using negative powers of 2. Basically, we define a binary number, $x$, such that the $n'th$ bit in $x's$ expansion is 1 if $n$ is in the set. Consider the following statement:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{-i} = 2-2^{-n}$

If our algebraic model of MA is recursive then I can compute this sum for $\frac{1}{2}$ which is $2-2^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 1.29...$. Now, I can subtract $2^{-n}$ from this sum for every $n$ in our non-recursive set. This gives me a number where the $n'th$ bit of the number is $0$ if $n$ is in our set. Note that I don't actually have to compute such a number. I only have to show such an algebraic number exists and can be used as an oracle for a TM.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a non-standard model of MA? I would have thought the "standard model" would be $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}$, and all other models would be non-standard.

Comment: Do you have a reference to algebraic numbers being a model of MA?

Comment: @Wojowu: The closest I have to a reference is [Even XOR Odd Infinities](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119375/even-xor-odd-infinities).

Comment: I don't believe you that the algebraic numbers form a model. Let $\phi(x)$ be the property $x \geq 0$. This fails to satisfy the induction axiom.

Comment: The finite models are the only "standard models" of MA. The integers are not a model of MA because of the four square theorem. We can use the four square theorem to define the non-negative integers. This is an inductive proper subset showing the integers fail to satisfy first order induction.

Comment: $\geq$ is not definable in MA.

Comment: "Almost certain applies to MA" is not really the same thing as "applies to MA", and you should be wary of things which are "almost certainly".

Comment: @RussellEasterly Do you have a proof that $\leq$ is not definable? It's not obvious to the tired me who is currently sitting here.

Comment: @RussellEasterly Note that it's not a question of whether "$\ge$" is definable in a *theory*, but rather in the *structure* in question.

Comment: Tennenbaum's theorem says that no countable nonstandard model of PA has a computable addition or multiplication.  It does not literally apply to other theories, although by examining the proof we can see that only some finite number of axioms of PA are actually used, and so the theorem will apply to fragments of PA that contain these axioms. There is no reason I can see to suspect that the particular axiom of PA that is changed in MA would not be used in the proof of the theorem, and so I can't see why the theorem should apply to MA.

Comment: The only axiom that is different is $\exists x(Sx=0)$. You think Tennenbaum's theorem requires $\forall x(Sx \neq 0)$?

Comment: Re: your edit, the decimal expansion of any algebraic number is computable - this is a standard exercise. So that line of attack won't work. Also, you still haven't given any real evidence for Tennenbaum's theorem holding for $MA$. In response to your claim "$MA$ is a relatively strong theory," note that $MA$ doesn't prove anything resembling unique prime factorization - *which is one of the key components of Tennenbaum's theorem*! So I don't see how you possibly view $MA$ as a "relatively strong theory" in this context.

Comment: You have given no justification for your claim that the algebraic numbers are a model of MA.

Comment: @RussellEasterly Re: your most recent comment, yes, I certainly do. And you should be suspicious of that axiom based on how many models pop up as soon as you drop it - why do you think it would be safe to leave out? (Also, have you actually read the proof of Tennenbaum's theorem? If not, that might help.)

Comment: Personally, I don't think MA has any infinite models. Emil Jerabek and others have stated any algebraically closed field is a model of MA. See the comments in [Even XOR Odd Infinities](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119375/even-xor-odd-infinities) on MathOverflow. Which axiom do you think fails?

Comment: @RussellEasterly Wait, what? Emil et al gave good reasons for algebraically closed fields to form models of $MA$, so why do you think it has no infinite models? And the accepted answer talks about the $p$-adics . . . which are infinite! Or did you make a typo?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Tennenbaum's proof uses prime factorization to encode sets. This can be done using negative powers of two like I show above.

Comment: @RussellEasterly **Only if the resulting number is algebraic**, which it won't be - see my edit to my answer. (And, I *still* don't understand your previous comment about infinite models . . .)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am an ultrafinist and I don't think any infinite set exists. I consider MA a tool to prove PA is inconsistent. I think Tennenbaum's theorem really proves non-standard models are inconsistent.

Comment: @RussellEasterly That's not what Tennenbaum's theorem says at all. I think I've hit the point of diminishing returns - I'm going to bow out now. Hopefully my answer helps you understand why incomputable sets can't be coded into algebraic numbers; and maybe you can clarify what exactly you mean by "Tennenbaum for MA," and why you think it holds. If you do, and ask that as a separate question, I'll try to answer it; but I think I'm done here.

Comment: @ARussellEasterly: you say "Emil Jerabek and others have stated any algebraically closed field is a model of MA", but is was **you** that stated that in your MO question.  Emil Jerabek's answer there was that the 2-adic integers gives a model of MA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Let me preface this by saying that I'm very surprised by your claim that Tennenbaum "almost certainly" applies to $MA$. Do you have any evidence for this? Also, what precisely does "nonstandard model" mean in the context of $MA$?*

Do you mean the algebraic *real* numbers, or the algebraic *complex* numbers?

The algebraic reals do not, in fact, form a model of $MA$. The nonnegative algebraic numbers are definable - they are the ones which have square roots (note that the square root of an algebraic number is algebraic).

Now this means that induction fails in the algebraic reals - $0$ is nonnegative, and the successor of a nonnegative number is nonnegative, but there are non-nonnegative (heh) algebraic numbers.

As a side note, of course, this means that the usual ordering is definable as

> $x\le y\iff \exists z(z*z+x=y)$,

contra your comment above.

For the algebraic *complex* numbers, things are more complicated; they might form a model of $MA$, but I'm not sure.

---

As to the question of whether the structure $(A, +, \times)$ ($A$ the set of algebraic reals, $+$ and $\times$ usual addition and multiplication) has a recursive copy: it does, but the proof is nontrivial. The difficulty, roughly, is the following: I need some way of "naming" algebraic numbers so that each one has exactly one name, and I can effectively find names for the sum and product of two named algebraic numbers.

Here's how to do that: say that a *pre-code* is a pair $(p, I)$, where

- $p$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients, and
- $I$ is an open interval with rational endpoints.

A precode is a *code* if

- $p$ has exactly one zero in $I$.

Fix some appropriate mechanism $\eta$ for coding precodes by naturals. Now we have two important facts: the theory of the structure $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R}, +, \times)$ is decidable (Tarski https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers), and each element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is definable in $\mathcal{R}$. This combines to show the following:

- The set of codes is computable.
- The relation $\sim$ on codes, given by $(p, I)\sim (q, J)$ iff the unique zero of $p$ in $I$ is the unique zero of $q$ in $J$, is computable.

Say that $(p, I)$ is a *good code* if there is no earlier (in the sense of the coding-by-naturals $\eta$) code $(q, J)$ which is $\sim (p, I)$. Then by the above, the set of good codes is computable. Again applying decidability of $\mathcal{R}$ and the definability of each rational in $\mathcal{R}$, the operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ on good codes defined below are computable:

- $(p, I)\oplus (q, J)=(r, K)$ iff $(r, K)$ is a good code and the unique zero of $r$ in $K$ is the sum of the unique zeroes of $p$ in $I$ and of $q$ in $J$.
- $(p, I)\otimes (q, J)=(r, K)$ iff $(r, K)$ is a good code and the unique zero of $r$ in $K$ is the product of the unique zeroes of $p$ in $I$ and of $q$ in $J$.

A similar argument also works for the algebraic complex numbers.

---

EDIT: As to your question

> what prevents me from encoding a non-recursive set as an algebraic number?

Note that a key component of Tennenbaum's theorem is coding *via prime factorization*; that is, the (semi)ring structure of any model of arithmetic has a lot of definable complexity. (This is also a driving force in Godel's theorem.) By contrast, prime factorization isn't interesting in a field. So "what prevents" this coding is the complete absence of any of the analogous semiring-theoretic complexity!

And indeed, the theory of the field of algebraic numbers is decidable. So this really is a crucial bit of complexity that's dropped.

---

**EDIT**: Based on your recent edit to the question, I believe this will be relevant:

> If $z=a+bi$ is algebraic, then the decimal expansions of $a$ and $b$ are each computable.

This is a standard exercise. The rough outline is: suppose $z=a+bi$ is algebraic, and fix a polynomial $p$, rational $c$ and $d$, and a rational $q$ such that the unique root of $p$ in $\{y: \vert y-(c+di)\vert<q\}$ is $z$. We now use the decidability of $\mathbb{C}$ to compute the decimal expansions of $a$ and $b$. For example, we can use $Th(\mathbb{C})$ to answer questions of the form

> Is $z$ in the closed box $[1.356+2.837i, 1.357+2.838i]\times [12.458-0.001i, 12.459-0i]$?

By asking a series of such questions, we can compute the decimal expansion of $a$ and $b$. A slight difficulty is caused if either/both $a$ and $b$ are rational; but this is easily handled by a separate case (note that every rational is definable).

This is why we can't code a non-computable set into the *decimal expansion* of an algebraic number. And the lack of semiring-theoretic complexity prevents other kinds of Tennenbaum encoding. Based on all this, I **again** ask: *do you have any real reason to believe Tennenbaum holds for $MA$?*

Comment: $2 \leq 3$ because $(2+1=3) mod 4$. $3 \leq 2$ because $(3+3=2) mod 4$. Tennenbaum's theorem is a proof by contradiction. That is why I ask if the is any reason why I can't encode a non-recursive set as an algebraic number.

Comment: @RussellEasterly I do not understand your comment. What does mod 4 have to do with the specific structure (the algebraics) you're asking about? Also, *why do you think Tennenbaum applies to $MA$*?

Comment: Note that in my answer, I show that $\le$ is definable in *a specific structure* - the fact that that same definition behaves differently in a different structure says nothing relevant. In particular, I proved that the initial structure - the algebraic reals - is not a model of $MA$.

Comment: Noah, Tarski. Yes. In the complex case, by the way, you need to appeal to a different argument why the theory is decidable. But it is.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually, we can also use a completely different argument: every computable field has a computable algebraic closure (Frohlich/Sheperdson).

Comment: Oh. That's pretty cool.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know, right? It's very surprising, especially given (a) the complexity of the splitting set and (b) the fact that ZF doesn't even prove that every field has an algebraic closure! Interestingly, it's non-uniform in the following sense: if $F$ is a computable field, then there is a computable algebraically closed field $G$ and a computable field embedding $e: F\rightarrow G$, but we can't additionally guarantee that the *image* of $e$ is computable!

Comment: Well, ZF proves that every computable field has *an* algebraic closure... :)

Comment: "Do you have any real reason to believe Tennenbaum holds for MA?" I think this will make a great question which I will submit soon. Do you have any reason to think Tennenbaum's theorem doesn't apply to MA?

Comment: @RussellEasterly Yes, for example: (1) the proof of Tennenbaum's theorem frequently uses facts not provable in $MA$. (2) $MA$ has a wide variety of models, e.g. the $p$-adic integers for every $p$, which are easily describable. Also, **what is a standard model in the context of $MA$**? Without defining this, it's utterly unclear what "Tennenbaum for $MA$" even means - and if we just take "standard model" to mean "the usual model of arithmetic," then the fact that the algebraically closed numbers satisfy $MA$ **immediately disproves** Tennenbaum for $MA$.